# Multiple recyclerview in fragment

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have fragment that contain multiple horizontal recyclerview . the content of this recyclerview fetch from server and depends on different situation the number of this recyclerview may be in range of 2 to 30 , how can i handle this problem ??

Comment: Show your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want to achieve is **NestedRecyclerView**.As you have not elaborated your problem below are some links you can go through.
[Easily Adding Nested Recycler View](https://android.jlelse.eu/easily-adding-nested-recycler-view-in-android-a7e9f7f04047)

[Horizontal recyclerview in Vertical recyclerview](https://android-pratap.blogspot.com/2015/12/horizontal-recyclerview-in-vertical.html)

Also,I would like to suggest you to please elaborate your problem statement. For ex: the data structure , adapter/activity codes.

Hope,the above links will help you.